# Error: _util_useScrollPosition__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

````
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useScrollPosition = () => {
  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updatePosition = () => {
      setScrollPosition(window.pageYOffset);
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", updatePosition);

    updatePosition();

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", updatePosition);
  }, []);

  return scrollPosition;
};

export default useScrollPosition;```

im importing this in another file

```ts
import useScrollPosition from "../app/hooks/useScrollPosition";

export function Header() {
  const scrollPosition = useScrollPosition();
  console.log(scrollPosition);```

im getting the same error
**Error: **_app_hooks_useScrollPosition__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default(...) is not a function
````

i changed the file name to tsx, ts, js and its not working and the import file is correct when I hover on it it goes to the right file. I tested this code in my other project works fine.

Comment: im also using nextjs, with tailwind

Comment: sounds like more info is needed here.. seems you are for example using webpack no?